# Xcode 6 run app wirelessly

Tags: xcode6

Eventhough, Xcode 6 displays in iOS devices section my iOS 8.0.2 running iPad2 wirelessly and builds normally my app, when it tries to run end up the the following message:

Cannot retrieve value from the passcode locked device.
Please check your setup and try again. (0xE8000016).

Any ideas ?

Comment: Same here, although wired and this very device has no passcode *sigh*. I advise to file a rdar.

Comment: same here on iOS 8.1 and Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the device to make sure Xcode is referencing the correct device.

In my case, Xcode detected one of my iPads nearby as a wireless device (which happened to be passcode locked), but when I plugged in my *other* iPad it mistook it for the wireless one.